# how to parse email for values coming as google calendar request in any format

Tags: html, node.js, email

i have developed application to read mail in node

```
var MailListener = require("mail-listener2");

    var mailListener = new MailListener({
    username: "some@gmail.com",
    password: "yourpass",
    host: "imap.gmail.com",
    port: 993, // imap port 
    tls: true,
    tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
    mailbox: "INBOX", // mailbox to monitor 
    searchFilter: ["UNSEEN"], // the search filter being used after an IDLE notification has been retrieved 
    markSeen: true, // all fetched email willbe marked as seen and not fetched next time 
    fetchUnreadOnStart: false, // use it only if you want to get all unread email on lib start. Default is `false`, 
    mailParserOptions: {streamAttachments: true}, // options to be passed to mailParser lib. 
    attachments: true, // download attachments as they are encountered to the project directory 
    attachmentOptions: { directory: "attachments/" } // specify a download directory for attachments 
  });

  mailListener.start(); // start listening 

  // stop listening 
  //mailListener.stop(); 

  mailListener.on("server:connected", function(){
    console.log("imapConnected");
  });

  mailListener.on("server:disconnected", function(){
    console.log("imapDisconnected");
  });

  mailListener.on("error", function(err){
    console.log(err);
  });


  mailListener.on("mail", function(mail, seqno, attributes){
    // do something with mail object including attachments 
    console.log("emailParsed", mail);
    console.log("****seprator******");
    var temp=mail;
    somethingNew(temp);
    // mail processing code goes here 
  });

  mailListener.on("attachment", function(attachment){
    console.log(attachment.path);
  });

  function somethingNew(temp){
  console.log("****seprator******");
  console.log("****seprator******");
  console.log("****seprator******");


  console.log("****seprator******");
  console.log("****seprator******"); 
  console.log(temp);
  console.log("****seprator******");
  console.log("****seprator******");
  readm(temp);


  }

 function readm(temp){
  //console.log(temp);
  console.log("****seprator******");
  console.log("****seprator******");
  console.log("****seprator******");

  console.log("****seprator***html***");
  console.log(temp.html);


  console.log("****seprator****text**");
  console.log(temp.text);
  //console.log( temp.text.Title);


  console.log("****seprator****alternatives**");
  console.log(temp.alternatives);
  //console.log(temp.alternatives[content]);

  console.log("****seprator****headers**");
  console.log(temp.headers);

  console.log("****seprator***subject***");
  console.log(temp.subject);

  console.log("****seprator***messageId***");
  console.log(temp.messageId);

  console.log("****seprator****priority**");
  console.log(temp.priority);

  console.log("****seprator****from**");
  console.log(temp.from);

  console.log("****seprator****replyTo***");
  console.log(temp.replyTo);

  console.log("****seprator***to***");
  console.log(temp.to);

  console.log("****seprator***date***");
  console.log(temp.date);

  console.log("****seprator***attachments***");
  console.log(temp.attachments);


  //console.log(temp.);


  }
```

now i have got reply as html and text

```
        { html: '<div style=""><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="8" border="0" summary="" style="width:100%;font-family:Arial,Sans-serif;border:1px Solid #ccc;border-width:1px 2px 2px 1px;background-color:#fff;" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"><tr><td><meta itemprop="eventStatus" content="http://schema.org/EventScheduled"/><div style="padding:2px"><span itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"><meta itemprop="name" content="Google Calendar"/></span><meta itemprop="eventId/googleCalendar" content="5vm603umqd3bh29m0j4jjqv8lk"/><div style="float:right;font-weight:bold;font-size:13px"> <a href="https://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=VIEW&amp;eid=NXZtNjAzdW1xZDNiaDI5bTBqNGpqcXY4bGsgbW9oaXQxMjVAbQ&amp;tok=MjIjc2luZ2hzaHJ1dGk4QGdtYWlsLmNvbTE4YTE2ZGEyNTk0ODAyY2U2M2JmODUzYmUwMTVjY2U3YmJiY2Q4ODA&amp;ctz=Asia/Calcutta&amp;hl=en" style="color:#20c;white-space:nowrap" itemprop="url">more details &raquo;</a><br></div><h3 style="padding:0 0 6px 0;margin:0;font-family:Arial,Sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;color:#222"><span itemprop="name">hello</span></h3><div style="padding-bottom:15px;font-size:13px;color:#222;white-space:pre-wrap!important;white-space:-moz-pre-wrap!important;white-space:-pre-wrap!important;white-space:-o-pre-wrap!important;white-space:pre;word-wrap:break-word">hello say</div><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" summary="Event details"><tr><td style="padding:0 1em 10px 0;font-family:Arial,Sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:#888;white-space:nowrap" valign="top"><div><i style="font-style:normal">When</i></div></td><td style="padding-bottom:10px;font-family:Arial,Sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:#222" valign="top"><time itemprop="startDate" datetime="20150216T100000Z"></time><time itemprop="endDate" datetime="20150216T110000Z"></time>Mon Feb 16, 2015 3:30pm &ndash; 4:30pm <span style="color:#888">India Standard Time</span></td></tr><tr><td style="padding:0 1em 10px 0;font-family:Arial,Sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:#888;white-space:nowrap" valign="top"><div><i style="font-style:normal">Where</i></div></td><td style="padding-bottom:10px;font-family:Arial,Sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:#222" valign="top"><span itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place"><span itemprop="name">Basavanagudi, Bengaluru, Karnataka, India</span><span dir="ltr"> (<a href="https://maps.google.co.in/maps?q=Basavanagudi,+Bengaluru,+Karnataka,+India&amp;hl=en" style="color:#20c;white-space:nowrap" target="_blank" itemprop="map">map</a>)</span></span></td></tr><tr><td style="padding:0 1em 10px 0;font-family:Arial,Sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:#888;white-space:nowrap" valign="top"><div><i style="font-style:normal">Calendar</i></div></td><td style="padding-bottom:10px;font-family:Arial,Sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:#222" valign="top">Mohit Kumar</td></tr><tr><td style="padding:0 1em 10px 0;font-family:Arial,Sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:#888;white-space:nowrap" valign="top"><div><i style="font-style:normal">Who</i></div></td><td style="padding-bottom:10px;font-family:Arial,Sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:#222" valign="top"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td style="padding-right:10px;font-family:Arial,Sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:#222"><span style="font-family:Courier New,monospace">&#x2022;</span></td><td style="padding-right:10px;font-family:Arial,Sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:#222"><div><div style="margin:0 0 0.3em 0"><span itemprop="attendee" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><span itemprop="name">Shruti Singh</span><meta itemprop="email" content="singhshruti8@gmail.com"/></span><span style="font-size:11px;color:#888"> - organizer</span></div></div></td></tr><tr><td style="padding-right:10px;font-family:Arial,Sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:#222"><span style="font-family:Courier New,monospace">&#x2022;</span></td><td style="padding-right:10px;font-family:Arial,Sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:#222"><div><div style="margin:0 0 0.3em 0"><span itemprop="attendee" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><span itemprop="name">Mohit Kumar</span><meta itemprop="email" content="mohit125@gmail.com"/></span></div></div></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></div><p style="color:#222;font-size:13px;margin:0"><span style="color:#888">Going?&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><wbr><strong><span itemprop="action" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/RsvpAction"><meta itemprop="attendance" content="http://schema.org/RsvpAttendance/Yes"/><span itemprop="handler" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/HttpActionHandler"><link itemprop="method" href="http://schema.org/HttpRequestMethod/GET"/><a href="https://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=RESPOND&amp;eid=NXZtNjAzdW1xZDNiaDI5bTBqNGpqcXY4bGsgbW9oaXQxMjVAbQ&amp;rst=1&amp;tok=MjIjc2luZ2hzaHJ1dGk4QGdtYWlsLmNvbTE4YTE2ZGEyNTk0ODAyY2U2M2JmODUzYmUwMTVjY2U3YmJiY2Q4ODA&amp;ctz=Asia/Calcutta&amp;hl=en" style="color:#20c;white-space:nowrap" itemprop="url">Yes</a></span></span><span style="margin:0 0.4em;font-weight:normal"> - </span><span itemprop="action" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/RsvpAction"><meta itemprop="attendance" content="http://schema.org/RsvpAttendance/Maybe"/><span itemprop="handler" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/HttpActionHandler"><link itemprop="method" href="http://schema.org/HttpRequestMethod/GET"/><a href="https://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=RESPOND&amp;eid=NXZtNjAzdW1xZDNiaDI5bTBqNGpqcXY4bGsgbW9oaXQxMjVAbQ&amp;rst=3&amp;tok=MjIjc2luZ2hzaHJ1dGk4QGdtYWlsLmNvbTE4YTE2ZGEyNTk0ODAyY2U2M2JmODUzYmUwMTVjY2U3YmJiY2Q4ODA&amp;ctz=Asia/Calcutta&amp;hl=en" style="color:#20c;white-space:nowrap" itemprop="url">Maybe</a></span></span><span style="margin:0 0.4em;font-weight:normal"> - </span><span itemprop="action" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/RsvpAction"><meta itemprop="attendance" content="http://schema.org/RsvpAttendance/No"/><span itemprop="handler" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/HttpActionHandler"><link itemprop="method" href="http://schema.org/HttpRequestMethod/GET"/><a href="https://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=RESPOND&amp;eid=NXZtNjAzdW1xZDNiaDI5bTBqNGpqcXY4bGsgbW9oaXQxMjVAbQ&amp;rst=2&amp;tok=MjIjc2luZ2hzaHJ1dGk4QGdtYWlsLmNvbTE4YTE2ZGEyNTk0ODAyY2U2M2JmODUzYmUwMTVjY2U3YmJiY2Q4ODA&amp;ctz=Asia/Calcutta&amp;hl=en" style="color:#20c;white-space:nowrap" itemprop="url">No</a></span></span></strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<wbr><a href="https://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=VIEW&amp;eid=NXZtNjAzdW1xZDNiaDI5bTBqNGpqcXY4bGsgbW9oaXQxMjVAbQ&amp;tok=MjIjc2luZ2hzaHJ1dGk4QGdtYWlsLmNvbTE4YTE2ZGEyNTk0ODAyY2U2M2JmODUzYmUwMTVjY2U3YmJiY2Q4ODA&amp;ctz=Asia/Calcutta&amp;hl=en" style="color:#20c;white-space:nowrap" itemprop="url">more options &raquo;</a></p></td></tr><tr><td style="background-color:#f6f6f6;color:#888;border-top:1px Solid #ccc;font-family:Arial,Sans-serif;font-size:11px"><p>Invitation from <a href="https://www.google.com/calendar/" target="_blank" style="">Google Calendar</a></p><p>You are receiving this email at the account mohit125@gmail.com because you are subscribed for invitations on calendar Mohit Kumar.</p><p>To stop receiving these emails, please log in to https://www.google.com/calendar/ and change your notification settings for this calendar.</p></td></tr></table></div>',
  text: 'You have been invited to the following event.\n\nTitle: hello\nhello say\nWhen: Mon Feb 16, 2015 3:30pm - 4:30pm India Standard Time\nWhere: Basavanagudi, Bengaluru, Karnataka, India\nCalendar: Mohit Kumar\nWho:\n     * Shruti Singh - organizer\n     * Mohit Kumar\n\nEvent details:https://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=VIEW&eid=NXZtNjAzdW1xZDNiaDI5bTBqNGpqcXY4bGsgbW9oaXQxMjVAbQ&tok=MjIjc2luZ2hzaHJ1dGk4QGdtYWlsLmNvbTE4YTE2ZGEyNTk0ODAyY2U2M2JmODUzYmUwMTVjY2U3YmJiY2Q4ODA&ctz=Asia/Calcutta&hl=en\n\nInvitation from Google Calendar: https://www.google.com/calendar/\n\nYou are receiving this email at the account mohit125@gmail.com because youare subscribed for invitations on calendar Mohit Kumar.\n\nTo stop receiving these emails, please log in tohttps://www.google.com/calendar/ and change your notification settings forthis calendar.\n',
  alternatives: 
   [ { contentType: 'text/calendar',
       charset: 'utf-8',
       method: 'REQUEST',
       transferEncoding: '7bit',
       content: 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nPRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN\nVERSION:2.0\nCALSCALE:GREGORIAN\nMETHOD:REQUEST\nBEGIN:VEVENT\nDTSTART:20150216T100000Z\nDTEND:20150216T110000Z\nDTSTAMP:20150216T082334Z\nORGANIZER;CN=Shruti Singh:mailto:singhshruti8@gmail.com\nUID:5vm603umqd3bh29m0j4jjqv8lk@google.com\nATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=\n TRUE;CN=Mohit Kumar;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:mohit125@gmail.com\nATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=TRUE\n ;CN=Shruti Singh;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:singhshruti8@gmail.com\nCREATED:20150216T082333Z\nDESCRIPTION:hello say\\nView your event at https://www.google.com/calendar/e\n vent?action=VIEW&eid=NXZtNjAzdW1xZDNiaDI5bTBqNGpqcXY4bGsgbW9oaXQxMjVAbQ&tok\n =MjIjc2luZ2hzaHJ1dGk4QGdtYWlsLmNvbTE4YTE2ZGEyNTk0ODAyY2U2M2JmODUzYmUwMTVjY2\n U3YmJiY2Q4ODA&ctz=Asia/Calcutta&hl=en.\nLAST-MODIFIED:20150216T082333Z\nLOCATION:Basavanagudi\\, Bengaluru\\, Karnataka\\, India\nSEQUENCE:0\nSTATUS:CONFIRMED\nSUMMARY:hello\nTRANSP:OPAQUE\nEND:VEVENT\nEND:VCALENDAR\n' } ],
  headers: 
   { 'delivered-to': 'mohit125@gmail.com',
     received: 
      [ 'by 10.140.237.204 with SMTP id i195csp1401035qhc; Mon, 16 Feb 2015 00:23:34 -0800 (PST)',
        'from mail-yk0-x24a.google.com (mail-yk0-x24a.google.com. [2607:f8b0:4002:c07::24a]) by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id d4si2229730yho.21.2015.02.16.00.23.34 for <mohit125@gmail.com> (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128); Mon, 16 Feb 2015 00:23:34 -0800 (PST)',
        'by mail-yk0-x24a.google.com with SMTP id 131so4000864ykp.1 for <mohit125@gmail.com>; Mon, 16 Feb 2015 00:23:34 -0800 (PST)' ],
     'x-received': 
      [ 'by 10.236.229.194 with SMTP id h62mr14905407yhq.95.1424075014402; Mon, 16 Feb 2015 00:23:34 -0800 (PST)',
        'by 10.52.246.135 with SMTP id xw7mr20174605vdc.8.1424075014237; Mon, 16 Feb 2015 00:23:34 -0800 (PST)' ],
     'return-path': '<3BqnhVAwJCIs7x2vw7w698xNv1px0.r3113wx8GHKv1px0.r31@calendar-server.bounces.google.com>',
     'received-spf': 'pass (google.com: domain of 3BqnhVAwJCIs7x2vw7w698xNv1px0.r3113wx8GHKv1px0.r31@calendar-server.bounces.google.com designates 2607:f8b0:4002:c07::24a as permitted sender) client-ip=2607:f8b0:4002:c07::24a;',
     'authentication-results': 'mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of 3BqnhVAwJCIs7x2vw7w698xNv1px0.r3113wx8GHKv1px0.r31@calendar-server.bounces.google.com designates 2607:f8b0:4002:c07::24a as permitted sender) smtp.mail=3BqnhVAwJCIs7x2vw7w698xNv1px0.r3113wx8GHKv1px0.r31@calendar-server.bounces.google.com; dkim=pass header.i=@gmail.com; dmarc=pass (p=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=gmail.com',
     'dkim-signature': 
      [ 'v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=20120113; h=mime-version:reply-to:sender:auto-submitted:message-id:date:subject :from:to:content-type; bh=xccv5QmpAhdrXCRvN37v0iA8Ln7Hh1s9f/RuHGj8gdU=; b=RcxTzn/lPUS8AMsNraUuVZqvinCuWYsBL5UKynyEBivj7kbWy7m787NSVEbnCPdhXi 5IN8qg9jLiKBBNMYEn6U0RnrXp0c/hHzQw1Ps7kgMu6lOIgUqR9SF0BCPPkCJYOWTv38 Z4776HYIHvd1aWvAbvsdHyxgeDAII9Jdd40GXKR3cGLy5w/iDPzf7xlDzRkbWagSB7GE 4KIsje19ABtWq5S3Bsr+g85ZXce/qdPgOHgBR3tsHg+qs/cj9o9g0pKmxdP4PF/A6Ijl Tn3/lKtBbeA20+Sq/o1H1fGog4USfSU/GQZSIHmB/RoQ64v1L87fJ5Q3ciCuHx4P/KNf kAhg==',
        'v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=gmail.com; s=20120113; h=mime-version:reply-to:sender:auto-submitted:message-id:date:subject :from:to:content-type; bh=xccv5QmpAhdrXCRvN37v0iA8Ln7Hh1s9f/RuHGj8gdU=; b=Pe3VflZDDdJHkM/QVivnJxT3GG6dC6x8a3+c7wFgUIEJq4PvDh+ucuKfD9/ApQNFnm ZrhGol9JYOhgca25ELIFxAFF9rCsRsLL0t2qTwb+RAKQKFeSDO0tgYZqSi3z7/d3wbuW dPf2Ayr+X++WeC+SVfpWMBDUV7PVuoljRxBW1C7BhTqoIgcIcdVr0RJulQ5x88ta3+PS DKiqagGoLNDyQ9GxybEjQQJQ/0/vrqvuJDo8RllJB/oFIEwAjg/Rq5fFiH5tHoq/QjOv nwpEYu3BJd1t7rVcwYBEiXGVlBWAQl+7q/4WaAf4bzDnTnINQh8kbE2rCI5QdxZOyOD+ /usw==' ],
     'mime-version': '1.0',
     'reply-to': 'Shruti Singh <singhshruti8@gmail.com>',
     sender: 'Google Calendar <calendar-notification@google.com>',
     'auto-submitted': 'auto-generated',
     'message-id': '<001a1133e8885b71e1050f304dcf@google.com>',
     date: 'Mon, 16 Feb 2015 08:23:34 +0000',
     subject: 'Invitation: hello @ Mon Feb 16, 2015 3:30pm - 4:30pm (Mohit Kumar)',
     from: 'Shruti Singh <singhshruti8@gmail.com>',
     to: '"mohit125@gmail.com" <mohit125@gmail.com>',
     'content-type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary=001a1133e8885b71b7050f304dce' },
  subject: 'Invitation: hello @ Mon Feb 16, 2015 3:30pm - 4:30pm (Mohit Kumar)',
  messageId: '001a1133e8885b71e1050f304dcf@google.com',
  priority: 'normal',
  from: [ { address: 'singhshruti8@gmail.com', name: 'Shruti Singh' } ],
  replyTo: [ { address: 'singhshruti8@gmail.com', name: 'Shruti Singh' } ],
  to: [ { address: 'mohit125@gmail.com', name: '' } ],
  date: Mon Feb 16 2015 13:53:34 GMT+0530 (IST),
  attachments: 
   [ { contentType: 'application/ics',
       fileName: 'invite.ics',
       contentDisposition: 'attachment',
       transferEncoding: 'base64',
       generatedFileName: 'invite.ics',
       contentId: 'c83293db0d87bcf03733897cac0a181d@mailparser',
       stream: [Object],
       checksum: '1a14bcaf023d2f754a596c1f50f497d3',
       length: 1062 } ] }
```

using  the response i want to  parse email id ,title ,subject for calendar event and  time for scheduling and timezone name or value ,how should i do that ?

Comment: Why do you want to scrape those details from a web page? I am sure google calendar offers a real API like other calendar providers do. One that is meant for being used by other software components. Like WebDav or the like.

Comment: @arkascha my requirements is such that i need to parse through mail , my requirement is about telling about particular time is empty or not , i have worked with calendar api ,but my requirement is diff